# HttpContext.Current is null in WCF custom messageencoder

Tags: wcf, httpcontext, wcf-extensions

I've been added `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"` attribute to serviceHostingEnvironment config in my WCF service project, `AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required` to service, but still get null HttpContext.Current value in ReadMessage. How to fix this problem?
I use custom binding with http transport + custom host factory.

Comment: I found that problem persists only with long-length requests (126kb for example).

Comment: Could you share your configuration file?

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual [webconfig.txt](https://ru.scribd.com/document/329497243/Web-Config)